# Ionic React props.match.params doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router-dom, ionic-react

I'm building a site to display real estate with React and Ionic.

I have this routing in my **App.tsx**

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <Nav />
    <IonRouterOutlet id="first">
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/all-properties" component={Properties} />
      <Route exact path="/property/:id" component={Property} />
    </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

And I link to the single `"/property/:id"` page in my website like this:

```
<Link to={"/property/" + variableId}> ... </Link>
```

Now on my `"/property/:id"` page I can access the id from the URL like this:

```
useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  console.log(props.match.params.id); // This works the first time
});
```

The problem is, when I click back to say the home screen, and then visit another of my `"/property/:id"` pages, the `props.match.params.id` stays the same. It doesn't update.

What could be done to fix it?

Comment: some cod around how the route is accessed would be helpful

Comment: @AaronSaunders I'm not sure what you mean, could you expand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that it was Ionics lifecycle method that was the problem.

My solution was to make a useEffect instead like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(props.match.params.id)
}, [props.match.params.id])
```

Comment: Thanks, was stuck on this forever. Didn't expect that useIonViewDidEnter wouldn't have the props ready... FYI it also works with the `useParams()` hook from `react-router-dom` instead of `props.match.params.id`

Comment: It works great with useIonViewWillEnter and multiple params also,  thanks